# GAE web.xml to fallback to React-Router

Tags: google-app-engine, reactjs, react-router, redux-router

I'm trying to build a new frontend on top of an existing GAE application using React, Redux and Redux-Router. My problem is figuring out how to make GAE always fallback to the html page where Redux-Router will take care of the routing.

Right now, if I go to '/' the app works fine and the navigation is perfect. When I refresh the page GAE kicks in and tries to find the route.

How do I configure GAE to always go the same html? oh, only if the url doesn't start with api/ to serve my data?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Should have mentioned that the backend is Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.xml (under 2.5) allows you to wildcard the start or the end of the path (but not anywhere in the middle)

You should achieve what you're after by using `/*` - which is basically any path not mapped by another rule. Your `/api/*`rule should continue to work.

Comment: For some reason it works fine locally but when deployed to GAE it fails with a strange error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No forced path servlet for /index.html

Comment: Are you trying to load index.html in the browser? You can map that as a static resource in appengine-web.xml

Comment: I'm already serving it from static resources...changing it to JSP file and setting 404 to fallback to the main jsp seems to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Python in the backend the following would do the trick in your `main.py` - where `IndexHandler` is the handler you use to render the "html page where Redux-Router will take care of the routing".

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', IndexHandler)],
    config=config,
    debug=DEBUG)
```